# Right click on Synaptic Touchpad not working on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: touchpad, 14.10, synaptics

I have successfully installed Ubuntu on my Aspire E3 112 and after a bit of fannying around with setting a System Password in the BIOS and trusting the Grub2 EFI settings, I have a stable system that boots in to both Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 with Bing.

**BUT**

The right click doesn't work on the Synaptic Touchpad.

No matter where I click on the touchpad it is recognised as a left click. Grrrrrr

I've tried installing the GPointing Device Setting but  there aren't any config settings for right click.

I've heard that Synaptics have a product (Synaptics Gesture Suite for Linux -  SGS-L) but it's only available to OEM suppliers.

Has anybody else encountered this?

Has anybody got any suggestions worth trying or somewhere I can find a driver/application that will work?

I have run xinput and have the following printed for core pointer:

> Virtual core pointer             is=2    [master pointer   (3)]
>
> > Virtual core XTEST pointer   id=4    [slave pointer  (2)]
> >
> > SYN1B7D:01   06CB:2991   UNKNOWN   id=11   [slave pointer  (2)]

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10002622/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions though. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very kind person on the Acer Community Forum supplied me with a doc for ArchLinux and Synaptics Touchpads that has proven quite educational (always good).

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Buttonless_TouchPads_.28aka_ClickPads.29

```
xinput list-props "SYN1B7D:01 06CB:2991 UNKNOWN" | grep Capabilities
```

Gives me the following: 
Synaptics Capabilities (295):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0

WHich shows, by the 3rd digit being 0, that I have no physical right button.

There are quite a few options using xorg to re-map the mouse buttons in the doc that don't look too difficult but I think I will give using a double finger click a go and see how I get on.

Answer (score 6):

Just add:

```
Option "ClickPad"         "true"
Option "EmulateMidButtonTime" "0"
```

in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`

Something like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "ClickPad"         "true"
        Option "EmulateMidButtonTime" "0"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
        Option "SecondarySoftButtonAreas" "58% 0 0 15% 42% 58% 0 15%"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me in Ubuntu 14.10

1. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and use the following command:

   ```
   sudo nautilus
   ```

This will open a window with sudo privileges and allow you to change and save root files.

2. Find and open the file: `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`
3. Locate the paragraph:

   ```
   # This option enables the bottom right corner to be a right button on clickpads
   # and the right and middle top areas to be right / middle buttons on clickpads
   # with a top button area.
   # This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
     Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
        Option "SecondarySoftButtonAreas" "58% 0 0 15% 42% 58% 0 15%"
      EndSection
   ```
4. Add two extra lines before **Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"** :

   ```
        Option "ClickPad"         "true"
        Option "EmulateMidButtonTime" "0"
   ```

(first one enables right click and the second middle click)

5. Now save the changes and Log out/Log in. The right click should be working now!