# Acer Notebook rightclick not working

Tags: laptop, touchpad, acer, synaptics

I have a problem with my acer e5-571 running Ubuntu 14.04.

The touchpad isn't recognized correctly: I have no right click.

**Output from `xinput list`:**

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
  ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
  ↳ SYN1B7E:01 06CB:2970 UNKNOWN                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
  ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
  ↳ Power Button                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
  ↳ Video Bus                                   id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
  ↳ Power Button                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
  ↳ Sleep Button                                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
  ↳ HD WebCam                                   id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
  ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
  ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                            id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Sometimes there is no cursor at all, and I have to restart a few times till I get one.
Any help / workarounds are greatly appreciated.

**Output from `Synclient`:**

```
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 49
    RightEdge               = 1187
    TopEdge                 = 48
    BottomEdge              = 850
    FingerLow               = 25
    FingerHigh              = 30
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 67
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 30
    HorizScrollDelta        = 30
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.130976
    TouchpadOff             = 2
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 3
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 0
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 7
    VertHysteresis          = 7
    ClickPad                = 0
```

Comment: which kernel are you running - 3.13 or 3.16? `uname -a` - maybe uplifting to 3.16?

Comment: I´m running 3.16.

Comment: ?? you have posted this as well and it says you are running archlinux - so what are you really running - arch or ubuntu? https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193367

Comment: also - what is the output of `synclient` ?

Comment: Sry was on vacation, thus the delay. I edited in the output from ´synclient´. I tried archlinux and faced the same problem there. Currently I run ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution for my VN7-571G-56N0
Touchpad:

```
↳ SYN1B7F:00 06CB:2970 UNKNOWN
```

My solution isn't nice but its a workaround. Obviously the Touchpad isn't detected by the driver. I don't have another explanation for such a bad configured driver.

Step 1: [Download enable-rightbutton.sh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=enable-rightbutton.sh)

Step 2: Identify your touchpad ID using xinput

Step 3: Activate the Clickpad parameter with

```
synclient Clickpad=1
```

Step 4: Run the enable-rightbutton.sh with your Touchpad ID as parameter e.g.

```
enable-rightbutton.sh 11
```

If this works for you too, you just have to put all this into the startup. I made this by adding "synclient Clickpad=1" at the front of the Script and put it into startup (open dash-> type in startup -> open the programm -> add an entry with the script with your ID as parameter)

[This may be a useful link.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection)  Especially the Part 'Enabling right button click for clickpads on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS'

Just found a german link related to the topic, but because the asker is german it may help him:
[Touchpad at ubuntuusers.de](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Touchpad) You can load the settings a cleaner why by defining a new configuration for the touchpad using udev. There are plenty of possibilites to reconfigurate the synaptics driver e.g. changing the sensibilty or auto-turn off the touchpad while writing. It may help you with your other issue.

*UPDATE* My Touchpad works well with Ubuntu 15.04 Kernel 3.19 now. Anyway its still marked as UNKNOWN in xinput and theres still an error in dmesg.

Comment: Thanks that fixed the right click issue! I just have to check if the issue where the trackpad does not work at all some times is resolved as well.

Comment: Error where it's not working at all after reboot/put to sleep stills persists though.

Comment: Yea i got an error too after reboot, but after i send it to canonical it never came back. I can't help you with the fact that your courser disappears because i cannot reproduce it. The workaround i found is very dirty i think and you should replace it with a proper solution which may come with a new Kernel which recognizes the the Touchpad. I added a german link where you can read some more about configurating the synaptics driver.

Comment: My girlfriend is using this notebook now, I will update it to 15.04. We will see if it works out of the box there. Still got strange issues where sometimes there is no mouse at all and she has to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my vn7-591G-74QT. Adding

```
    Option "ClickPad"         "true"
    Option "EmulateMidButtonTime" "0"
```

to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf solved it.

[Right click on Synaptic Touchpad not working on Ubuntu 14.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579645/right-click-on-synaptic-touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-10)

Answer (score 0):

Type the following commands into the Terminal:

```
sudo su -c "echo options psmouse proto=exps > /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.modprobe"
sudo reboot
```

Comment: No difference afterwards. Could you explain what this does?