# Ubuntu change touchpad behaviour

Tags: 14.10, touchpad, synaptics

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.10 on my AlienWare 13' Notebook and I really don't like the touchpad behaviour there. The two things I dislike are that the "right click" only works when I click the touchpad with two fingers. I'd prefer it if it recognizes the right click when I clicked the right side of the touchpad. And the other annoying behaviour is that I can't move the cursor with a second finger while clicking. For example when I wanna move a folder I click it with one finger and try to move it with an other, but it doesn't recognize my second finger. :(

Can someone please help me to configure it correctly? I'm new to Ubuntu and don't know where I can change those settings.

Here is my xinput output:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL068B:00 06CB:76E9 UNKNOWN              id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_FHD                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older thread, but I just got my Wifi and touchpad to work on my alienware 13...
Had to blaklist the i2c_hid module (for the touch pad), update the ath10 module and kernel to 3.19 for the Wifi.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problems with my Touchpad on my Acer Aspire VN7-571G-56N0.

Type`xinput` into the Terminal to see which Touchpad you are using.
Then you may follow the steps i described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/590418/381721).

Comment: That doesn't work for me.. It said something like "Synaptics softkeys not set" when I started the sh file.

Comment: Whats your output of xinput?

Comment: I edited my question.. I tried it with ID 14.