# Alienware 13 touchpad not working under any distro [DLL068B:00 06CB:76E9] [hid-rmi]

Tags: xorg, mouse, touchpad, synaptics, alienware

Well, as the title explains that's my problem, I'm using 3.18 kernel, and this are my thoughts:

First of all the touchpad wasn't showing up in xinput while I was expecting something like:

```
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL068B:00 06CB:76E9 UNKNOWN              id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

the result was:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SI                                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SI                                        id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_FHD                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I have a USB-mouse connected to the computer so it must be the SI.

I was amazed because I have read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590332/ubuntu-change-touchpad-behaviour) question asking for changing the behaviour of the touchpad while mine isn't even detected so I went to the dmesg, that shows:

```
[   11.910114] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:76E9.0004: Scanning PDT...
[   11.918335] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:76E9.0004: Found F34 on page 0x00
[   11.922470] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:76E9.0004: Found F01 on page 0x00
[   11.925806] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:76E9.0004: Found F12 on page 0x00
[   11.938596] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:76E9.0004: Found F54 on page 0x01
[   11.946371] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:76E9.0004: Found F30 on page 0x02
[   11.960820] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:76E9.0004: Found F55 on page 0x03
[   11.968612] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:76E9.0004: rmi_scan_pdt: Done with PDT scan.
[   11.968678] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:76E9.0004: No 2D sensor found, giving up.
[   11.968739] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:76E9.0004: Error while initializing F11 (-19).
[   11.968839] input: DLL068B:00 06CB:76E9 as /devices/pci0000:00/INT3433:00/i2c-0/i2c-DLL068B:00/0018:06CB:76E9.0004/input/input7
[   11.969042] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:76E9.0004: input,hidraw3: <UNKNOWN> HID v1.00 Mouse [DLL068B:00 06CB:76E9] on 
[   11.969125] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:76E9.0004: Device failed to be properly configured
```

And the /var/log/Xorg.0.log file shows something like:

```
[    26.245] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DLL068B:00 06CB:76E9 (/dev/input/event7)
[    26.245] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
```

So the thing it's it can be a problem with either hid-rmi or a problem with the X configuration (probably the hid-rmi but not for sure) or both which is fun. If anybody have any idea about the problem, it'll be welcomed.

Best regards, me.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Why do you use 3.18 kernel?

Comment: Ok, I tried Ubuntu 15.04, first of all the computer doesn't boot and got stuck into a loop that said something about nouveau, I solved it adding nomodeset to the kernel parameter so I somehow managed to boot into 15.04, and surprise!

In xinput it showed as Synaptics and apparently Xorg recognizes the thing and it's under the mouse and touchpad configuration in the configuration tool.

But, the touchpad isn't working at all.

In synclient it was working and I tried to change the TouchpadOff from 2 to 0 with no sucess, it's imposible to change TouchpadOff parameter even with root.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/592925/dell-inspiron-3551-unresponsive-touchpad

Answer (score 4):

I found an solution:

Type in the terminal

```
sudo su
echo 'blacklist i2c_hid' >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
depmod -a
update-initramfs -u
```

and reboot

Hope did work for you!!

Answer (score 0):

Got this working on my Alienware 13 with Ubuntu 15.04 by blacklisting the i2c_hid module.

You have to edit the following file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add this line at the end:

```
blacklist i2c_hid
```

Reboot and you should be good to go.