# Kubuntu 14.04 - right click not working on touchpad - Acer V3-572G-75CA

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, synaptics, tap-to-click

In my laptop touchpad it's not possible to get the right click action, neither by pressing the right button nor tapping the touchpad with two fingers.
The output of xinput is:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0501:00 04F3:300B UNKNOWN             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and the output of "xinput list-props "ELAN0501:00 04F3:300B UNKNOWN" is

```
    Device Enabled (136):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (138): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (260):     1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (261):       2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (262):       1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (263):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (264):  129, 3110, 126, 2221
    Synaptics Finger (265): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (266):       180
    Synaptics Tap Move (267):       175
    Synaptics Tap Durations (268):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (269):       0
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (270):  75
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (271):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (272):       7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (273):     79, 79
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (274): 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (275):   1, 0
    Synaptics Move Speed (276):     1.000000, 1.750000, 0.050012, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (277):    2
    Synaptics Locked Drags (278):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (279):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (280):     2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (281):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (282):     0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (283):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (284):     0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (285):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (286): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (287):        10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (288): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (289):        30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (290): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (291):      1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (292):      0
    Synaptics Gestures (293):       1
    Synaptics Capabilities (294):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (295): 32, 31
    Synaptics Area (296):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (297):     19, 19
    Device Product ID (255):        1267, 12299
    Device Node (256):      "/dev/input/event12"
```

I notice that the two button are not really separated from the touchpad (like in [this](http://www.notebookcheck.net/fileadmin/Notebooks/Acer/Aspire_V5-573G-54208G50aii/Acer-Aspire-V5-573-2.jpg) photo). Perhaps this type of touchpad requires a special configuration...
Any suggestions is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should try activating the Clickpad-Setting.
This might help you:
[Acer Notebook rightclick not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587917/acer-notebook-rightclick-not-working/590418#590418)