# Acer Chromebook Touchpad Clicking Moves Mouse

Tags: mouse, touchpad, acer, crouton

I just finished installing Ubuntu to my Acer C710 Chromebook, and I have a minor problem with the touchpad. When ever I try to click using the touchpad it ends up moving the mouse at the same time. I am having to use touch to click right now, but its kinda annoying when i need to do things like double click or click and drag. If anyone knows anything about this topic it would be mich appreciated!
Thanks!

```
xinput -
(trusty)louis@localhost:~$ xinput
� Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
�   ��� Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
�   ��� Cypress APA Trackpad (cyapa)                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
� Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ��� Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ��� Power Button                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ��� Video Bus                                   id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ��� Power Button                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ��� Sleep Button                                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ��� AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

What I got when running the command "uname -a" (I need help updating the kernel)

Linux localhost 3.4.0 #1 SMP Fri May 8 12:28:58 PDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux –

Comment: is anybody seeing this? i really need help plz... is there another place i could post this problem

Comment: Please run it this way `LANG=C xinput` it will give output in English.

Comment: And please specify your Ubuntu and kernel version.

Comment: ill do lang=c xinput and post what i get but im on 14.04 and i just ran the command sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid so i think the kernel im on is 3.19 an answer below said to install kernel 4.1rc5 but i don't know how so i cant

Comment: i did lang=c xinput and got the exact same thing... the results are already in english

Comment: OK. It can be seen. But these question marks are weird.

Comment: wait i just did uname -a
to double check my kernal versoin and it said im on 3.4... really strange....

Comment: Just post `uname -a`. I will explain how to install mainline kernel. It is easy do not worry.

Comment: here  Linux localhost 3.4.0 #1 SMP Fri May 8 12:28:58 PDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: what do i do from here...

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: 14.04 with lxde

Comment: So install 3.19 kernel first as I said in my answer `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid` and reboot.

Comment: ok ill give it a go!

Comment: i did sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid and it said linux-generic-lts-vivid is already the newest version but when i do uname -a it says Linux localhost 3.4.0 #1 SMP Fri May 8 12:28:58 PDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 /x86_64 GNU/Linux –    is there a way i can manually upgrade my kernel? also just in case u inux localhost 3.4.0 #1 SMP Fri May 8 12:28:58 PDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux – didn't know because im not sure if i posted it the way i installed ubuntu is through crouton

Comment: I suggest asking another question regarding this weird problem with kernel upgrade. I do not have an answer.

Comment: You can try to `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic-lts-vivid`. Maybe you did not let it finish or something. Or some manual setting in grub.

Comment: ok i guess im gonna make another post about my kernel not upgrading because untill that gets fixed im stuck,,,

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/632443/crouton-ubuntu-14-04-lxde-cant-upgrade-kernel

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your Touchpad isn't recognized correctly. I had the same problem too and found a workaround:
[Acer Notebook rightclick not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587917/acer-notebook-rightclick-not-working/)

You should try this.

If this doesn't work you should try the Ubuntu 15.04 final beta. I tried it and it seems that my Touchpad is supported with Kernel 3.19.

Comment: unfortuanly this didnt work... my touchpad is recognized by ubuntu..... i will try upgrading to 15.04 and hope that works..... D;

Comment: Could you add the output of "xinput" to your post?

Comment: im upgrading to 15.04 right now and then after that ill do xinput and see what i get

Comment: ok so i couldn't even upgrade to 14.10 because after i upgraded and tried to start crouton i would get errors and it wouldn't start and so i went back to 14.04, anyway i added xinput to my post

Answer (score 0):

Support of this touchpad has been added not long ago to linux kernel. That means it is not perfect.

First of all try to install mainline kernel 4.1rc5 from [Ubuntu mainline kernel ppa](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).

There were a lot of fixes after 3.19. But you may try 3.19 first on 14.04 by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

There are a lot more fixes in "next" kernel branch. If nothing helps, I can make a dkms package with the latest updates.

That is nearly all that could be done, except editing sources.