# Dell XPS 13 Cannot Right Click

Tags: dell, touchpad, trackpad

I recently set up Ubuntu on a new Dell XPS 13 (9343), and I've been having a bit of trouble with the trackpad. It cannot right click. Here's what I've tried so far:

Checking xinput: Output of `xinput -list` was:

```
$ xinput -list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Mouseemu virtual mouse                    id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN              id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Mouseemu virtual keyboard                 id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

After checking all of the possibilities, I determined that `DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN` was the only one that when disabled, caused the trackpad to stop working. None of the others had any effect.

Naturally, I ran `xinput --test 12`, and I got the following results:

1. Regardless of which button (left or right) I pressed, button press 1 and button release 1 were called.
2. If I pressed the trackpad in two places, at slightly different times (talking a few dozen milliseconds, but it could not be at the same time), then it would output the button press 3 and the button release 3 that I would expect from a right click. These clicks could be anywhere on the trackpad as long as the timing was correct.

It is also worth noting that xdotool still works correctly, and that things like right click worked fine on Windows.

If any of you could help me figure out what is going on, that would be wonderful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
Option "ClickPad"         "true"
Option "EmulateMidButtonTime" "0"
```

in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`

This worked for my dell 9343 running 14.10

more info

[Right click on Synaptic Touchpad not working on Ubuntu 14.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579645/right-click-on-synaptic-touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-10)

Answer (score 1):

I've got an xps 13 and have had issues with the trackpad also. I managed to fix it by complete accident the other day, you can try this and see if it does the job for you too: go to your 'additional drivers' application from the launcher, look through and see if you have an unknown driver, enable it. The driver will say it's from the 'sommerville's dino platform'. I have no idea what that is exactly, but it's made the trackpad work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the "two finger click problem" by using `30-synaptics.conf` config file.

Try it with this one for example:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        # Enabling tap-to-click is a perilous choice that begets needing to set up palm detection/ignoring. Since I am fine clicking my touchpad, I sidestep the issue by disabling tapping.
        Option "TapButton1" "0"
        Option "TapButton2" "0"
        Option "TapButton3" "0"
    # Using negative values for ScrollDelta implements natural scroll, a la Macbook default.
        Option "VertScrollDelta" "-80"
    Option "HorizScrollDelta" "-80"
        # https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics has a very buried note about this option
    # tl;dr this defines right button to be rightmost 7% and bottommost 5%
    Option "SoftButtonAreas" "93% 0 95% 0 0 0 0 0"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection
```

Create the file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-synaptics.conf`.

You can edit this config file to better fits your preferences.

[The Arch Wiki page on Synaptics trackpad](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics) explains all possible configurations in detail.

Comment: Does not work. The page http://hgdev.co/wp-content/uploads/50-synaptics.conf seems to be to a spam or invalid site.

Comment: @user92240 thanks for noting, the answer have been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xinput set-prop "PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me very quickly and hassle-free...

Install gnome-tweak-tool

sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
Launch it.
Go to Keyboard & Mouse
Click on 'Area' under 'Mouse click emulation'

Credit: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/8gptsc/comment/dydpifj/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3