# Right-click on Touchpad not working after update to 18.04 LTS

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, 18.04

I have a Lenovo Yoga 910-13IKB. I was running Ubuntu 17.10 with no issues. I upgraded to 18.04 LTS and now my right-click on my touchpad does not register. I can only left-click.

I already tried the steps listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579645/right-click-on-synaptic-touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-10?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but they did not fix the issue.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: @L.D.James Here is the link to my post:  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390099&p=13759687#post13759687

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1. Install `gnome-tweak-tool`
2. open `gnome-tweaks`
3. go to Keyboard & Mouse
4. under Mouse Click Emulation, select Area.
5. Reboot.

Comment: Wonder how to open gnome-tweaks? Please guide.

Comment: If you don't want too use the terminal command line you can install search for "gnome tweaks" in Ubuntu Software. Once installed, open the applications menu and search for "Tweaks".

Comment: any idea why "Fingers" stop working after Suspend?

Comment: @Tosho, I think it's because "fingers" mode is used for screen scrolling.

Comment: The "area" option works great on my Lenovo ideapad 330S-15IKB with Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: Sorry for a non-contributing comment but it again, it looks like dumbing down gnome settings at it's best. Your solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

Install gnome-tweak-tool by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Write gnome-tweaks in terminal and press Enter.
This will open gnome-tweaks.
Under Keyboard & Mouse option, go to Mouse Click Emulation.
There are three options there. Choose Area.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the issue was with my new lenovo ideapad laptop 330 for which right click will work when you press it with 2 fingers.

Might be case for someone else also so added as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, your hint also worked for a Lenovo Yoga 11e. Might be a Lenovo thing.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Umar Soleh is excellent. This answer is just to point out an alternative which is a bit more complex, but more comprehensive because you have access to additional settings that `Tweaks` does not expose.

1) Install Dconf-Editor. From the Terminal:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install dconf-editor -y
```

2) Open Dconf Editor and accept the warning to be careful!

3) Find touchpad settings at `/org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad`

4) Select `click-method`; turn off `Use default value`; set `Custom value` to `areas` or `fingers` [Umar suggested `fingers` which for me feels the most natural]

You may be interested in other settings in this section (along with my personal recommendations):

```
* send-events: Set to `disabled-on-external-mouse`
* tap-and-drag: Disable (an annoying feature!)
* two-finger-scrolling-enabled: Enable (the default)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its new feature provide ubuntu 18. I install the

> gnome-tweak-tools

and there are 3 options for Mouse Emulations. Finger, Area, and Disabled. Here the explanation

- **Finger**: use 2 fingers for right click
- **Area**: user right buttons for right click
- **Disable**: disable touchpad

By default its set as **Fingers**, so you can use pointer and middle finger at once for right click

Answer (score 0):

Mine is **Lenovo G510** Laptop.

I did tried to follow above answers but my external mouse was also not working to set the options.

So, I opened `Mouse Controls` and **Checked** and **Unchecked** the `Left handed mouse` option.

[image]

Restarted the laptop and it started working.

**P.S.** My Keyboard is working.